# How to create a custom Contact Picker in iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, cncontactstore

I have tried using the CNContactPickerViewController. It works fine when all the contacts need to be displayed or when I need to filter based on standard fields. But, I want to be able to filter based on a custom property. In this case I want to only show contacts that have been validated on the server. I can get the list of contacts that have been validated. How do I filter the CNContactPicker to only show these contacts?

Comment: it is good if you share your code

Comment: The new Contacts in iOS 9 will help.

Comment: I am using the new contacts framework. There is not much code except the standard        `code`  let contactPicker = CNContactPickerViewController()
        contactPicker.delegate = self;
        contactPicker.displayedPropertyKeys = [CNContactPhoneNumbersKey, CNContactTypeKey]
        
        
        self.presentViewController(contactPicker, animated: true, completion: nil) `code`.  I am not sure how to filter the contacts